# Turning a 6 value 1 dimensional numpy.ndarray into a 6 dimensional

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, n-dimensional

I have a numpy ndarray with 6 values in 1 dim.
These 6 values represent a point in 6 dimensions.
How do I convert it in numpy to get a 6d array?

Backstory: 
I need this 6d layout for my neural network. The training happend with 6d data. For making predicitons I fail to reshape the data.

Comment: What is the shape of your array and what is the expected output shape?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please. It is obvious to me what you want but that cannot be said for everyone and all future visitors without at least a coherent example.

Comment: import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
x.ndim # is 1

what I need is: shape (6,)

Comment: I don't think you want a `6d` array.  More likely there's confusion over shapes, (6,), (1,6), and (6,1).

Comment: Got it!
np.reshape(x, (1,-1)) did the trick.
This reshaped to (6,1) which was accepted.
I got confused by the dimensionality aspect from the thing im trying.
Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, is the solution of your requirement which you mentioned above in comments, but important thing to understand is `(6,)` is not a `6-dimensional` array. It's an array of shape `(6, )` is `1-dimensional` and consists of `6` elements.

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]) 
x = np.reshape(a, (6,))
print(x.shape)
```

Output:

`(6,)`

```
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.reshape

```
import numpy as np
# for example my numpy array having 6 elements is [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
# array([1, 2, 3, 4,5,6])
b = np.reshape(a, (-1,1))
```